# how to combine custom listview with action bar or setcontentview method?

Tags: android, listview, view, android-listview, android-actionbar

In API 8 we couldn't use `ActionBar`. So i was using horizontal layout(Layout top) with set of `Button`s using `setContentView` for my other apps. Now i implemented custom `Listview` which contains images and texts. So how to  implement `setContentView` (Top linear layout )or `ActionBar` above `Listview`? Which one i should use ? How to do that?

in `onCreate` method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS,mp));
}
```

In xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:src="@drawable/play" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_weight="40.00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Tittle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:text="@+id/Tittle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Descriprion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:text="@+id/Descriprion"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="16sp" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/options"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="9.52"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_light"
    android:src="@drawable/options" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom top bar to `setContentView()`. Then in your `getView()` of your `Custom Adapter` just `inflate` your layout for your custom `ListView`.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/) on using a custom `ListView`